# how to add a link to the background image in the css code

Tags: css

this is the css code

```
#header #phone{
  background: url(../images/icon.jpg) no-repeat right 0px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
}
```

my question is how can I add a link to the icon.jpg image

thanks

Comment: Don't. Background images are supposed to be **background**. If you want a content image, use a content image (`<img>`).

Comment: you should consider approving answers to some of the 6 other questions you've previously posted.  Its not hard and those answering your questions really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

one of the tricks is :

http://xavisys.com/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/

> make the link the same size as the
>   image . Since an anchor tag isn’t a
>   block level element, we need to force
>   it to display as “block" & hide the
>   text. This can be done using
>   “text-indent” and indenting the text
>   completely off.